# How to handle derived fields in a form

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have two form fields `base` and `value` I want `value` to be derived from `base` if it isn't supplied. Furthermore, it would be nice when the validation worked (I need a `value`).

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1SEs2lUwah55TlyL9HZe), it is a rough translation of my code from coffeescript, but the problems are the same. The same code, but not in plnkr (and coffeescript):

```
app.controller "MyCtrl",($scope) ->
  [$scope.derive, $scope.derived]  = [yes, no]
  changeBase = () ->
    if $scope.derive
      $scope.value = if $scope.derived = $scope.base isnt ''
          $scope.base + " complicated operation"
        else ''

  $scope.changeBase = changeBase
  $scope.changeVal = () ->
    if $scope.derive = $scope.val isnt ''
      changeBase()
    else 
      $scope.derived = false
```

Html:

```
<form name="form" ng-controller="MyCtrl" novalidate>
  Value<input type="text" ng-model="value" 
             ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"
             ng-change="changeVal()"
             required>
  <span ng-show="derived">Is derived</span>
  <br>Base <input type="number" ng-model="base" ng-change="changeBase()">
  <br>
  <span ng-show="form.$invalid">from is invalid</span>
</form>
```

I use debounce for not changeing `value` immediatly if the user has cleared the value field.
If I remove the `required` attribute i almost get the desired behaviour, but the validation isn't working anymore (obviously, i removed it). (I want to add a `button` that relies on `ng-disabled="$form.invalid"`)

**But sometimes the booleans (`derive`, `derived`) get into a wrong state and I don't know how to fix this.** 
Apart from that, if someone has a solution that doesn't look like logic hell or thousands lines of code for this simple task, I'd be grateful, too.

**Edit:** Some scenarios:

1. the user edits the `base` field, `value` should be the derived value..
2. the user edits the `value` field, `value` shouldn't change if he edits the `base` field
3. if the user empties the `value` field, it should behave like in 1.
4. if the user empties the `base` field and `value` was derived, `value` should be emptied

if neither `base` nor `value` are entered, the `form.$invalid` should true, and the corresponding classes should be set. Preferably would `form.value.$error.required` be `true`.

Comment: I really don't understand your workflow and what you want to happen. Maybe you should provide a few examples of what should happen depending on user input.

Comment: @joseM: added some scenarios. is it clearer now?

Comment: That's better, and I think I can work with that, but can you please also add some concrete examples?

Comment: @JoseM: I tried to boil it down, to get the complicated stuff out of the way, but sure: It's for an off project. It's supposed to be a browser only app. I want it to be possible for `value` to be user entered. If only `base` is given, the app will add a random number from 1 to 6 to `base` and store that as `value` in an object. Later on, the so created object will be "clonable": another call to `Math.random` will be made to generate it. Even more concrete it's for my RPG-Group, and some folks prefer rolling their dice themselves, thus I wanted to support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution, but if some better solutions come up, I'll gladly accept and upvote them.

The invalidation of `value` by `required` prevents the `changeVal` function that is supplied by `ng-change` to be triggered. Because of this, I moved the validation away. This is not perfect, since now the `<input>` for `value` isn't shown as the reason, why the form is invalid, but the form still is. (HTML is almost the same, except  there's no `required` attribute and one call to `changeVal` via `ng-init`). It feels a bit hackish, because actually I'm reimplementing a the `ng-required` directive as if it wasn't bound to a specific field (but it is)

```
app.controller "MyCtrl",($scope) ->
  [$scope.derive, $scope.derived]  = [yes, no]
  changeBase = ->
    if $scope.derive
      $scope.value = if $scope.derived = $scope.base isnt ''
          $scope.base + " complicated operation"
        else ''
    changeValOrBase()

  $scope.changeBase = changeBase
  $scope.changeVal = () ->
    if $scope.derive = $scope.val isnt ''
      changeBase()
    else 
      $scope.derived = false
    changeValOrBase()

  changeValOrBase = ->
    $scope.form.$setValidity("valueGiven",$scope.value != '' and $scope.value?)
```

With that i can add a message like this:

```
<div ng-message="form.$error.valueGiven">Please supply a base value or value</div>
```